# При обновлении страницы картинки дублируются

Tags: php, html, css

У меня есть сайт, на главной странице находится слайдер, на слайдере через класс `[videopathimage]` показывает 4 картинки, но каждый из этих картинок через класс `.player__video image` должны стоять в одном кружочке, только когда юзер нажимает на баттоны картинки должны меняться, все работает нормально, есть одно но, когда обновляю главную страницу, эти картинки флоутятся вниз, все 4 один за другим, но на несколько миллисекунд,и потом исчезают, кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? я искал в css коде, но ничего не нашел

Comment: слайдер, случаем, не slick?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вашу ситуацию, то это связанно с тем, что страница показывается пользователю быстрее чем срабатывает `JS скрипт` для вашего слайдера (который применяет к этим картинкам слайдер). Собсна отсюда такое поведение. Такую ситуацию надо обыгрывать, и способов куча

Comment: @humster_spb да, slick

Comment: @Manitikyl как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Здраствуйте у меня проблема я поставил на content изображение через background-image.Все бы ничего но при обновлении страницы эта картинка на секунду окрашивается в красный и снова нормальной стает подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить? Изображение в пнг!

Answer (score 2):

У slick-слайдера действительно есть такая проблема: пока не отработал скрипт, слайды в виде блоков показываются все один за другим. Есть разные пути решения.

**1.** Можно сделать прелоадер для сайта: пока всё окончательно не загрузилось, пользователь будет видеть только какую-то анимированную картинку.

**2.** Можно скрывать все слайды кроме первого (display: none), а по событию window.load (когда всё окончательно загрузилось) открывать их.

**3.** Можно задать блоку-обёртке слайдера фиксированную высоту (по размеру слайда) и overflow: hidden - тогда все слайды кроме первого не будут видны в процессе загрузки скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

Была аналогичная проблема, помогла фиксированная высота контейнера, до этого была auto.